# ERROR: Unknown template parameter: StaticFiles

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I get the following error when I try to deploy to aws Elastic Beanstalk.

```
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-695359152326 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
ERROR: InvalidParameterValue: Unknown template parameter: StaticFiles
ERROR: Failed to launch environment.
```

I am using a preconfigured dockerpython template with the following structure.

```
.
├── application.config
├── application.py
├── Dockerfile
├── Dockerrun.aws.json
├── iam_policy.json
├── LICENSE.txt
├── misc
├── NOTICE.txt
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap
│   ├── images
│   └── jquery
└── templates
    ├── aboutus.html
    ├── clients.html
    ├── commonheaderincludes.html
    ├── commonhtmlheader.html
    ├── footer.html
    ├── header.html
    ├── index.html
    └── services.html
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you solve this eventually? Having the same error...